# How to skip some then in promise(bluebird)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

Sample code:

```
Queues.findOne({_id: id})
.then(function(q) {
 var status = q.status;   
 //...
}).then(function(q) {
// A
}).then(function(q) {
// B
}).then(function(q) {
// C
}).then(function(q) {
// D
}).then(function(q) {
// E
}).then(function(q) {
// F
})
```

Depends on the status, the flow will different

if status is `1`, `A/B/C/D/E/F` should be all executed.

if status is `2`, `C/D/E/F` should be executed, how to skip `A` and `B` ?

if status is `3`, `E/F` should be executed, how to skip `A/B/C/D` ?

Comment: So you're passing `q` through your chain? Then just write it out literally, `if (q.status <= 1) // A`

Comment: I hope `.then(function(q) {
 var status = q.status;   
}).then(function(q) {
// A` has an important piece of code missing in your question that exists in the **actual code**, because `q` at `// A` is guaranteed to be `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Queues.findOne({_id: id}).then(function(q) {
  var status = q.status;
  var x = Promise.resolve();
  var y = status <= 1 ? x.then(A).then(B) : x;
  var z = status <= 2 ? x.then(C).then(D) : y;
  return z.then(E).then(F);
}
```